# Ruby/Rails Time.parse in input timezone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timezone

I have a string that contains ISO8601 formatted date and time with timezone. How can I get `Time` or `TimeWithTimezone` object  in the timezone specified in the string?

PC's timezone is '+01:00' and `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` is set to UTC. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.13)
irb(main):001:0> Time.parse '1990-01-23T00:11:22-07:00'
=> 1990-01-23 08:11:22 +0100
irb(main):002:0> Time.zone.parse '1990-01-23T00:11:22-07:00'
=> Tue, 23 Jan 1990 07:11:22 UTC +00:00
```

Here's what I want:

```
irb(main):001:0> Time.???? '1990-01-23T00:11:22-07:00'
=> 1990-01-23 00:11:22 -0700
```

How can I parse the string and get time object in the timezone specified in the string?

Comment: have you looked at http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Time.html?

Comment: @AndreyDeineko Yes, couldn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue was that you've used `Time`, whereas had to use `DateTime`:

```
DateTime.strptime('1990-01-23T00:11:22-07:00', "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
#=> Tue, 23 Jan 1990 00:11:22 -0700
```

## EDIT

To make it a `Time` class object, you can do something like this (somewhat ugly, but still it does its job):

```
date = DateTime.strptime('1990-01-23T00:11:22-07:00', "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
#=> Tue, 23 Jan 1990 00:11:22 -0700 
Time.new(date.year, date.month, date.day, date.hour, date.min, date.sec, date.zone)
#=> 1990-01-23 00:11:22 -0700
```

Comment: Is there no way to do it using Time class?

Comment: @xx77aBs edited the answer, so that you obtain Time class object